# Search for list in other list

Tags: r

I am an apprentice in R operations. Say I have the following two lists:

```
city_distance_reference <- list("City1" = 100, 
                                "City2" = 150,
                                "City3" = 300,
                                "City4" = 500,
                                "City5" = 25,
                                "City6" = 1050,
                                "City7" = 300,
                                "City8" = 250,
                                "City9" = 300,
                                "City10" = 512)

node_movement <- list("City2", "City10", "City6", "City2")
```

I want to return a list of distances as following:

```
node_distance <- list(150, 512, 1050, 150)
```

How do I do this in R-style (no `for` loop)? Note that `node_movement` could have duplicate cities in it (as above) but the elements in `city_distance_reference` are always unique.

Comment: Do you mean `city_distance_reference[unlist(node_movement)]` (with names) or `unname(city_distance_reference[unlist(node_movement)])` (without names)?

Comment: Unname works for me.

Comment: BTW, if you're creating `node_movement` manually, is there a reason you're using `list(...)` instead of `c(...)`?

Comment: Hi, I tried using ```c(...)``` for ```node_movement```, but the ```node_distance``` still comes out as a ```list```.  If you don't mind explaining the shortcomings of using ```list(...)``` for ```node_distance```?I can do some learning here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following should do the trick.

```
unname(city_distance_reference[unlist(node_movement)])
```

It will produce

```
[[1]]
[1] 150

[[2]]
[1] 512

[[3]]
[1] 1050

[[4]]
[1] 150
```

Comment: Add `unname` (based on the OP's last comment), show its results, and wrap it in a markdown code fence, and you're in business :-)

Comment: Thank you @r2evans!